# Cannot set forms above pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I know why but not the how.  I basically need to have the wallpaper an opaque background and nothing more.  Currently with the current settings my forms cannot be clicked on and the h2 and h3 headings are now opaque.  How do I get the forms to be usable again and the wording to not be opaque whilst the background is still opaque?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
 family=Bangers&family=Chelsea+Market&family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap');
 .grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "one two three" "one two three" "one two three";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 310px);
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Chelsea Market', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: teal;
}

.one {
  background-color: tomato;
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  position: relative;
  grid-area: two;
}

.two::after {
  background-image: url(./henry-perks-TStCoAiFjDY-unsplash.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: .40;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.three {
  background-color: tomato;
  grid-area: three;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.form1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two">
      <h1 class="title">CJ's Pizza Place</h2><br>
        <h2 class="menu">Menu</h3>
          <br>
          <h3 class="toppings">Toppings</h3>
          <form class="form1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="pepperoni">
            <label for="toppings1">Pepperoni</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="meatballs">
            <label for="toppings2">Meatballs</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="olives">
            <label for="toppings3">Mushrooms</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="olives">
            <label for="toppings4">Olives</label>
          </form>
    </div>
    <div class="three"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: your explanation of requirements are not clear above, can you pls explain what you want to achieve

Comment: Which part is not clear?  I want the background to be opaque and the form to be editable on the page...if you take the code I have youll see what I mean